# member variable default initialization template

Tags: c++

Iam using a non c++11 capable compiler that does not support default initialization on the class declaration.

Since i have some class that manages visualization and does contains tons of bool flags and other member i would like to write some template class that does the default init.

i could implement something like:

```
template <unsigned int I>
class UIntDef{
public: 
  UIntDef(unsigned int d=I):i(d){
    cout << "init i="<<d<<endl;
  }

  operator unsigned int&(){return i;}

  unsigned int i;
};
```

or

```
template <bool I>
class BoolDef{
public: 
  BoolDef(bool d=I):i(d){
    cout << "init i="<<d<<endl;
  }
  operator bool&(){return i;}
  bool i;
};
```

But i would also like to use the type as template parameter

```
template <type T, T I>
class Def{
public: 
  Def(T d=I):i(d){
    cout << "init i="<<d<<endl;
  }
  operator T&(){return i;}
  T i;
};
```

obviously the last example does not work.
Is there a way to achieve this or does already exist something like this?

Comment: what is the sense of the template? Default initialization with a given value works also. And writing `X<100> x;` instead of X `x(100)` seems not a good solution, because the code will have multiple instances.

Comment: the sense is to set the default value on declaration to avoid the need to additional add them to the initializer list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax in the template parameter list is wrong:

```
template <typename T, T I>
//            ^^^^
```

Apart from that, the code is completely correct - [here is a demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d4450d9cdcd919c).

Comment: ahhh, i thought the it does not work, because of the reference of the second parameter to the first one. i didn't realized the missing 'name'